# CMake when run from within Visual Studio 2022 couldn't detect compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2022

So after installing VS 2022 and downloading and compiling boost 1.82, I was trying to get a test project running, one that is supposed to compile cross platform (new feature in VS 2022 or was it there in previous versions as well??). I created a new VC++ project and solution from within VS as File > New > Project > CMake Project.

And after modifying the CMakeLists.txt file as:

```
...
set (BOOST_ROOT "C:/boost/boost")
set (BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "C:/boost/boost/include")
set (BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "C:/boost/boost/stage/lib")
set (BOOST_MIN_VERSION "1.82.0")
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON) 
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)  
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF) 
set(Boost_DEBUG ON)
find_package(Boost ${BOOST_MIN_VERSION} COMPONENTS date_time REQUIRED)
if (NOT Boost_FOUND)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Fatal error: Boost (version >= ${BOOST_MIN_VERSION}) required.")
endif()
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}) 
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
...
```

And then did Project > Delete Cache And Reconfigure

The trouble is that it is not able to find the boost libraries and I believe it is because it couldn't figure out what the compiler is:

```
....
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1862 ] Boost_VERSION_MAJOR = "1"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1863 ] Boost_VERSION_MINOR = "82"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1864 ] Boost_VERSION_PATCH = "0"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1865 ] Boost_VERSION_COUNT = "3"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1889 ] Boost_LIB_PREFIX = ""
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1890 ] Boost_NAMESPACE = "boost"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:953 ] _boost_COMPILER = "" (guessed)
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1926 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = "-mt"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2004 ] _boost_ARCHITECTURE_TAG = "" (detected)
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2008 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = "-"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2009 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = "-d"
....
```

Here the _boost_COMPILER  was detected as  `_boost_COMPILER = "" (guessed)`.

Any idea what could be wrong here.. VS is supposed to tell CMake about itself right since I am calling CMake from within it?

EDIT: Attaching entire output from CMake

```
1> CMake generation started for default configuration: 'x64-Debug'.
1> Command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" /c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:\Users\johns\source\repos\LogMon\out\install\x64-Debug" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja\ninja.exe" "C:\Users\johns\source\repos\LogMon" 2>&1"
1> Working directory: C:\Users\johns\source\repos\LogMon\out\build\x64-Debug
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1689 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1690 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = "ON"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1691 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = "ON"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1692 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = "OFF"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1693 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1694 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1726 ] BOOST_ROOT = "C:/boost/boost"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1727 ] ENV{BOOST_ROOT} = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1728 ] BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = "C:/boost/boost/include"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1729 ] ENV{BOOST_INCLUDEDIR} = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1730 ] BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = "C:/boost/boost/stage/lib"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1731 ] ENV{BOOST_LIBRARYDIR} = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1803 ] _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = "C:/boost/boost/include;C:/boost/boost/include;C:/boost/boost;PATHS;C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/sw/local/include"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1804 ] _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES = <unset>
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1819 ] location of version.hpp: C:/boost/boost/boost/version.hpp
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1859 ] Boost_VERSION = "108200"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1860 ] Boost_VERSION_STRING = "1.82.0"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1861 ] Boost_VERSION_MACRO = "108200"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1862 ] Boost_VERSION_MAJOR = "1"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1863 ] Boost_VERSION_MINOR = "82"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1864 ] Boost_VERSION_PATCH = "0"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1865 ] Boost_VERSION_COUNT = "3"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1889 ] Boost_LIB_PREFIX = "lib"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1890 ] Boost_NAMESPACE = "boost"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:953 ] _boost_COMPILER = "" (guessed)
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1926 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = "-mt"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2004 ] _boost_ARCHITECTURE_TAG = "" (detected)
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2008 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = "-"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2009 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = "-d"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2069 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "C:/boost/boost/stage/lib;C:/boost/boost/lib;C:/boost/boost/stage/lib;C:/boost/boost/lib;C:/boost/boost/../lib;C:/boost/boost/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2070 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "C:/boost/boost/stage/lib;C:/boost/boost/lib;C:/boost/boost/stage/lib;C:/boost/boost/lib;C:/boost/boost/../lib;C:/boost/boost/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
1> [CMake] CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1384 (message):
1> [CMake]   New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
1> [CMake]   targets
1> [CMake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
1> [CMake]   C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1507 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
1> [CMake]   C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2118 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
1> [CMake]   CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package)
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2255 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_date_time-mt-1_82;libboost_date_time-mt;libboost_date_time-mt;libboost_date_time-mt;libboost_date_time
1> [CMake] -- [ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2310 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_date_time-mt-d-1_82;libboost_date_time-mt-d;libboost_date_time-mt-d;libboost_date_time-mt;libboost_date_time
1> [CMake] CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
1> [CMake]   Could NOT find Boost (missing: date_time) (found suitable version "1.82.0",
1> [CMake]   minimum required is "1.82.0")
1> [CMake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
1> [CMake]   C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
1> [CMake]   C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2376 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
1> [CMake]   CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package)
1> [CMake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
1> 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe' '/c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:\Users\johns\source\repos\LogMon\out\install\x64-Debug" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja\ninja.exe" "C:\Users\johns\source\repos\LogMon" 2>&1"' execution failed with error: ''C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe' '/c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:\Users\johns\source\repos\LogMon\out\install\x64-Debug" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja\ninja.exe" "C:\Users\johns\source\repos\LogMon" 2>&1"' returned with exit code: 1'.
```

Comment: Could you copy the entire output from CMake?

Comment: @MilanŠ. Done... Just to update, instead of using cmake from within VS, I downloaded the CMake GUI and ran the above project. I am unfortunately running into the same error. I had just updated the machine to Windows 11 and installed latest VS. So my guess is something (probably the name of some registry variable) has changed with latest Windows and latest VS and CMake is not able to identify the default compiler on the machine because of that.

Comment: BTW: The newest version of boost is currently 1.81.0

Comment: @john_zac I've managed to replicate the issue and edited my answer. Note that there might be more unset variables that are causing the issue because I'm going from a different direction than you (I'm going from a working build to a not working one, with an older version). As you noted I think the Win11 update messed up some environment variables that boost relied on for detecting the compiler version (wild guess) manually setting the variables should fix the issue (at least locally) [find_Boost](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html)

Comment: I would also recommend a dependency manager [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/en/index.html) which started as a Microsoft community project and thus is to some degree unofficially supported by Microsoft. It contains most library packages (including Boost) and is much easier to work with. It downloads the packages in triplets (win/linux/macos) making cross-platform development much easier.

Comment: @Vertexwahn, the one in git is at 1.82 while the one at boost website is at 1.81

Answer (score 1):

After skimming through the entire log the issue seems to be elsewhere than you'd expect.

```
...
find_package(Boost ${BOOST_MIN_VERSION} COMPONENTS date_time REQUIRED) #<---
...
```

It says so at the bottom of the log:

```
#Missing date_time... i.e. it can't find a REQUIRED component
1> [CMake]   Could NOT find Boost (missing: date_time) (found suitable version "1.82.0",
1> [CMake]   minimum required is "1.82.0")
```

To properly debug this issue I would recommend going through the paths outputed by these variables here:

```
1> [...] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "C:/boost/boost/stage/lib;C:/boost/boost/lib;C:/boost/boost/stage/lib;C:/boost/boost/lib;C:/boost/boost/../lib;C:/boost/boost/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
1> [...] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "C:/boost/boost/stage/lib;C:/boost/boost/lib;C:/boost/boost/stage/lib;C:/boost/boost/lib;C:/boost/boost/../lib;C:/boost/boost/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
```

and double check that these libraries are present in the directories (they probably wont)

```
1> [...] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_date_time-mt-1_82;libboost_date_time-mt;libboost_date_time-mt;libboost_date_time-mt;libboost_date_time
1> [...] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_date_time-mt-d-1_82;libboost_date_time-mt-d;libboost_date_time-mt-d;libboost_date_time-mt;libboost_date_time
```

I would then check if these libraries exist in the boost folder at all. Chances are they won't and it will most likely be because they are either part of a different component or are just missing from your boost installation.

Try including whole boost to see if that is the case:

```
find_package(Boost ${BOOST_MIN_VERSION})
```

Hope it helps!

EDIT: I've managed to replicate your issue and truly it is due to the undetected compiler most likely. As when building the boost it appends the compiler as a suffix (or somewhere mid name) to the library. I.e. if you check the lib dir you can deduct which compiler was being used and perhaps force set the variable through `set(Boost_COMPILER "-vcXYZ")`.

Note that the `libboost_date_time-mt-d-1_82` is missing the compiler due to this unset variable. It should look like `libboost_date_time-vc142-mt-d-1_82` (if you compiled with vc142)

Comment: I tried force setting few variables and the boost issue got resolved... but there are other issues like it is complaining that CMAKE_CXX98_STANDARD_COMPILE_OPTION and CMAKE_CXX20_EXTENSION_COMPILE_OPTION is not set. I explored a bit and these variables are set in the file 

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\share\cmake-3.24\Modules\Compiler\MSVC-CXX.cmake.

All these are due to compiler not being detected by CMake. CMake would have probably picked up the above file if it had figured out the compiler to be MSVC.

Comment: At this point I am all set to give up on this as probably there are going to be other issues when this is resolved and I am not a CMake expert.

Comment: @john_zac I wouldn't give up yet. It seems that the Visual Studio borked up it's configuration of CMake i.e. it didn't include the proper toolchain files in cmake. 
First thing is first: You can include any valid cmake file within your own cmake files (as a dirty fix). I wouldn't go down that road. Instead I would ask if you've had installed Visual Studio before updating to Win11. I'm starting to believe that reinstalling Visual Studio might resolve the issues (and the CMake it installs). Maybe reinstall CMake C++ tools (through VS installer) - I would give that a try first. Maybe it's enough

Comment: I've went deeper into all the config files of the VS toolset chain. A hunch is telling me that most-likely some of the variables needed by CMake to configure the correct variables are missing perhaps try `MESSAGE(STATUS ${CMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_NAME_DEFAULT})` or you can try running cmake via CLI as such `cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64 -S/path/to/source -B/path/to/build_folder` and see what it inputs. My bet is 100% that this is CMake incorrectly setting the Toolset chain files (reinstalling the package might help)

Comment: Thanks. A reinstallation of VS fixed the issue. When I installed VS earlier, in the installer application, I had ticked 2 components: 1. Desktop development with C++. 2. Linux and embedded development with C++. Both had its own CMake sub packages which was probably the reason behind the all this mess. Thank you very much for helping out!!

Comment: Amazing! If you found my answer/discussion in anyway helpful I would greatly appreciate an upvote:) Best of luck with your future endeavours!